# Who killed this member of the Night's Watch in A Clash of Kings?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In [Chapter 19 of ACOK](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_19), Arya

> finds Yoren's body in the aftermath of their battle with Ser Amory Lorch and his men.

And she observes how he died:

> "The axe blow that had killed him had split his skull apart"

But who killed him?

Comment: Wasn't there a battle when Yoren died and Arya left the group? I always thought that Yoren simply died at the battle

Comment: There is [a theory](http://www.reddit.com/r/asoiaf/comments/2978et/spoilers_all_rorge_and_yoren_more_than_meets_the/) that he was killed by Rorge, a prisoner Arya saves along Jaqen H'ghar

Comment: Take note of the baddass way he died: "`They find <removed>'s body with the skull split by an axe and surrounded by the bodies of four enemies.`"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In [Chapter 14 of ACOK](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Clash_of_Kings-Chapter_14), Arya

> Throws an axe into the wagon for Jaquen, Biter, and Rorge. Rorge catches it and starts hacking at the wagon.

In the next chapter, they do not find an axe with the Night Watchman's body.

Later on in [AFFC Chapter 37](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Chapter_37), the "hound" is killed:

> His axe fell from limp fingers, and the two of them slammed together, Brienne's face mashed up against the dog's head helm.

Notice how this character wielded an axe, and that he is described as "thick and powerful" in [this summary](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rorge):

> Rorge is described as squat, bulky, and hairy, with black hair covering most of his body. He is also described as thick and powerful.

And consider him and his companions:

> **Rorge** is a strong man with nothing left to lose (either join the Night's Watch or die), who interestingly joins the Lannister guard after Yoren's death. **Biter** is too feral and too wild to weild any weapon when fighting Brienne, much less an axe. **Jaqen** is a faceless man and *should* not go around killing people for no reason.

There is plenty of motive, evidence, and opportunity to infer this person killed Yoren.

Comment: @Himarm http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer - Though I was hoping someone would beat me to it.

Answer (score 8):

No named person killed Yoren he just died in the battle.

Comment: Citation to back that up?

Comment: How can you cite a negative?